# Sparkle appcast signing: The update is improperly signed

Tags: xcode, macos, codesign, sparkle

I am trying to solve this issue and have had no luck. I am archiving the project and exporting with XCode in developer signed format.

What do I need to have set up to sign this update properly:

- On the project build settings page (Currently Developer ID:Jeremy Laurenson (XXXX))
- On the target build settings page (Currently Developer ID:Jeremy Laurenson (XXXX))

In my sparkle framework signing build script:

```
LOCATION="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}"/"${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}"
IDENTITY="Mac Developer: Jeremy Laurenson (XXXX)"
codesign --verbose --force --sign "$IDENTITY" "$LOCATION/Sparkle.framework"
```

In my app cast signing script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PROJECT_NAME=testapp

set -o errexit echo "Getting version of the app $PROJECT_NAME here in this directory." VERSION=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print

:CFBundleVersion" "$PROJECT_NAME.app/Contents/Info.plist")
DOWNLOAD_BASE_URL="http://www.map-pin.com/sparkle/testapp"
RELEASENOTES_URL="http://www.map-pin.com/sparkle/testapp/release-notes.html#version-$VERSION"

ARCHIVE_FILENAME="$PROJECT_NAME$VERSION.zip" DOWNLOAD_URL="$DOWNLOAD_BASE_URL/$ARCHIVE_FILENAME"

WD=$PWD

echo "Removing all previous $PROJECT_NAME*.zip"

rm -f "$PROJECT_NAME"*.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out...

You can either code sign using your AppleID, or code sign using the public/private keying method previously used by Sparkle, but not both.

The easiest method was to:

1. Remove all code signing steps in build settings of the app.
2. Download a fresh github version of sparkle [here](https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle) and similarly create a vanilla, unsigned framework.
3. Use that framework in your new project.
4. Archive, sign with dev ID
5. Use the above script, without the DSA signature:

   cat >"sparkle_appcast_update.txt" <
   Version $VERSION
   $RELEASENOTES_URL
   $PUBDATE


   EOF